# ¿Como coger la id de un usuario de una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando un proyecto y lo tengo bastante desarrollado, aunque hay un escollo que no logro solucionar. No se me da bien php.

He creado una base de datos donde tengo el registro de usuarios, con su id, su nombre, etc..

Estoy tratando de extraer la información para mostrarla en un punto en concreto, pero cuando hago la consulta para que me extraiga el id, no solamente me extrae su id, sino un segundo valor como NULL, tal como me aparece en esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para guardar los datos de los usuarios en la base de datos, tengo este código.

```
class Usuario extends BD
{
    private $nombre;
    private $apellido;
    private $idUsuario;
    

    /*Función para comprobar que existe el usuario*/

    public function existeUsuario($nombreUsuario, $pass){
        $md5pass = md5($pass);

        $query = $this->conectarBD()->prepare("select * from usuarios where usuario = :usuario and password = :pass");
        $query->execute(['usuario' => $nombreUsuario, 'pass' => $md5pass]);

        if($query->rowCount()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Una vez logueado, para mostrar su nombre y apellidos
    public function establecerUsuario($usuario){
        $query = $this->conectarBD()->prepare('select * from usuarios where usuario = :usuario');
        $query->execute(['usuario' => $usuario]);

        foreach ($query as $usuarioActual) {
            /*Asignamos a las variables el nombre y el usuario obtenido de la bbdd*/
            $this->nombre = $usuarioActual['nombre'];
            $this->apellido = $usuarioActual['apellidos'];
            $this->idUsuario = $usuarioActual['id_usuario'];
           
        }

       
    }

    public function getNombre(){
        echo $this->nombre." ".$this->apellido;
       
    }

    public function getIdUsuario(){
        /*También cojo el id el usuario en esta funcion para asociar la actividad al usuario */
        echo $this->idUsuario;
    }
}
```

y lo uso de esta manera

`$sql = "select * from actividades where id_usuario = 2";`

donde el 2 debería de ser el id del ususario, pero no me sale.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Muchas gracias

Comment: @BetaM borraste la imagen en la edición... revertí y ajusté la cosa pa que se vea lo que el OP busca

Comment: Cierto @Alfabravo me disculpo, me falló la edición :(, quise ajustar el formato y olvide regresar el link de la misma

Comment: Aparte de lo que te dice @gaidyjg, lo cual es correcto en cuanto a usar `fetch` para obtener los resultados de tu consulta. Veo en tu código algunas malas prácticas: 1. La doc dice claramente que no se debería confiar en rowCount() para determinar si hay filas en consultas SELECT. Para ello deberías usar `SELECT COUNT(*)` y obtener el resultado en sí de ese SELECT; 2. Tu modelo de datos no es conforme a la realidad. Aunque parezca más fácil, tu clase `Usuario` no debería nunca extender de una clase que sirve para conectar a la BD. Por decirlo de algún modo, desde el punto de vista metafísico

Comment: ... un `Usuario` no tiene nada que ver con una conexión a la BD en cuanto entidad. La relación entre `Usuario` y `BD` es meramente contextual y/o utilitaria. Pero como ente, un Usuario no procede de BD. Las clases que representan entidades deberían extender de clases de la misma naturaleza (por ejemplo, `Usuario` podría extender de `Persona`). Si diseñas la clase independiente de la BD, podrías mapear el resultado a la clase sin tener necesidad de hacerlo a mano, como haces en el método `establecerUsuario()`

Comment: muchas gracias por tus consejos, trataré de modificar el código y adaptarlo :)

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está en como devuelves los datos en php. Por lo que intuyo, estás usando PDO. Cuando haces el query en sql, deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
```

o

```
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS)
```

fetch te devolverá solo una fila concordante de resultados. Si lo haces así como lo tienes, te dará algún tipo de error. Lo otro es que haría un consulta de este tipo `select * from actividades where id_usuario = 2 limit 1` con eso dices que solo un usuario va a traer al sql.

Si necesitas más referencias, te dejo esto por [acá](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: muchas gracias gaidyjg, voy a probar como me dices!

Comment: Dale, cualquier cosa dejas saber si tienes algún problema.

Comment: he intentado hacer lo que me has indicado, he usado fetchAll puesto que me interesa luego recorrer con un foreach y lograr sacar la información correspondiente en función del id del usuario logueado.

cuando recorro con foreach para extraer la variable si que me sale como que el id es de tipo numérico, pero luego aparte la variable que tengo para la id del usuario en el loguin, me sigue devolviendo el número de ID seguido de NULL, es lo que no consigo comprender porque me sale así...

¿Alguna idea u orientación? Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: ¿Añadiste la forma en que querías tus datos? Es decir, `FETCH_OBJ` o `FETCH_CLASS`

Comment: Sí, lo he añadido como me dijiste, he hecho así 
``` $consultaID = "select id_usuario from usuarios";
                                $ejecutarConsultaID = $bd->conectarBD()->prepare($consultaID);
                                $ejecutarConsultaID -> execute();

                                $resultadosConsulta = $ejecutarConsultaID ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);``` 

Para luego esa info recorrerla con bucle foreach. Si imprimo la variable donde almacen esa info, me sale un array con la correspondiente info de cada usuario que tengo en la bbdd.

Comment: Y dices que el valor null no está por ninguna parte en ese arreglo, ¿correcto?

Comment: eso es, recorriendolo con bucle for y extrayendo la información de id me la extrae sin problemas como valor numérico. Pero luego si hago uso de la función que he creado para extraer el id del usuario y su nombre para usarlo en el loguin por ejemplo así ` $idUser = $usuario -> getIdUsuario();` me indica 2 (el id) es NULL